# Understanding products of NIGNX PLUS, Controller, Ingress Controller, and Instance Management

Tags: nginx

As far as I know, Instance Management and the Controller have the same functions, which managing NGINX Plus and the Instances. but it does not make more sense.
So my question is

- What are the differences between Instance Management and Controller?
- What is Ingress Controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Nginx Instance Management:** NGINX Instance Manager empowers you to

- Automate configuration and monitoring using APIs.

> **For example**, if you have multiple servers using Nginx then in Nginx Plus service provides a dashboard where all the events can be monitored, Including spikes on specific events, Or think as one of the servers has not been updated from having multiple VM, monitor the list of inventory. To achieve `nginx-agant` needs to install along with `Nginx server` on the `host`.

- Ensure your fleet of NGINX web servers and proxies have fixes for
  active CVEs
- Seamlessly integrate with third‑party monitoring solutions such as
  Prometheus and Grafana for insights

**Nginx Controller:** NGINX Controller is cloud‑agnostic and includes a set of enterprise‑grade services that give you a clear line of sight to apps in development, test, or production. With per‑app analytics, you gain new insights into app performance and reliability so you can pinpoint performance issues before they impact production.

> **Example:** To enable the ingress you did need an Ingress Controller to enabled first.

**Nginx Ingress:** Each LoadBalancer service requires its own load balancer with its own public IP address, whereas an Ingress only requires one, even when providing access to dozens of services. When a client sends an HTTP request to the Ingress, the host and path in the request determine which service the request is forwarded to.

> **For example** [Google Kubernetes Controller](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress)